# Returning an int[] from java to C using JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have  a C program that invokes a java program but I have a problem:
my java program returns an int [], how can I use JNI to get the result of it in C, since JNI only has CallIntMethod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are objects, so you can use `CallObjectMethod()`. Use `GetIntArrayElements()` to access the array elements.

Comment: +1 - though I don't see the relevance of `CallObjectMethod()` to this question.